# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'forEach'

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

Good day everyone,
I'm trying to make a javascript code to scan through all the input in my form like so:

```
<form> 
  <input class="formInputOne" />
<input class="formInputOne" />
<input class="formInputOne" />
<input class="button" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now I want my javascript code to scan through all of them and know if they are empty or not like so:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let formInputOne = document.querySelectorAll(".formInputOne").value;
  if (formInputOne.forEach == "") {
    console.log("All fields are required!");
  } else {
   console.log("Yay! All fields got values");
  }
});
```

I'm really curious to find out a way to loop through all the inputs and know if they contain values.

Please I'm using javascript, but if it can be done with jquery, no probs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Select inputs, loop through it, get value and log based on value

```
let inputs = $('.formInputOne').toArray(); //document.querySelectorAll('.formInputOne')
inputs.forEach(e => {
    let value = e.value.trim();
    if (value == "") {
        console.log("All fields are required!");
    } else {
        console.log("Yay! All fields got values");
    }
});

//Check if atleast one value is empty
let bool = inputs.map(a => a.value.trim()).some(a => a == "");
console.log('Empty value is present', bool);
```